# Using env variables in a Jenkinsfile function?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm triggering one Jenkins job from the other, all via Jenkinsfiles.

```
stage("Trigger another job")
{
    build([job:"Job2", wait:true, propagate:true, parameters: [string(name:'branch_my',value:"${env.ghprbActualCommit}")]])
}
```

Note that parameter `branch_my` is sent to `Job2`. However, the pipeline `Job2` needs to work even when `branch_my` is NOT defined, for example when it is triggered manually.

Jenkinsfile for `Job2` looks like:

```
pipeline
{
  // ...
  steps
  {
    customBranches()
    // etc...
  }
}


def customBranches()
{
    if ( env.branch_my != null)
    {
        sh "switch_to ${env.branch_my}"
    }
}
```

However, the `customBranches()` if statement never evaluates to `true`. When I do

`sh "echo 'Env branch_my is: ${env.branch_my} '"`

I get `Env branch_my is: some_value` , which is OK, and if statement should evaluate to `true` - but it does not.

I tried adding `${}` like so: `if ( ${env.branch_my} != null)`, but that failed completely: `No such DSL method "$" found`.

What's wrong with my `customBranches()`?

Comment: Don't test for `null`, because it also evaluates to `true` for empty strings. Simply do `if(env.branch_my) {…}` which evaluates to `true` only for non-empty, non-null strings.

Comment: Just tried `if(env.branch_my)` and it doesn't work, it evaluates to `false` even the variable is set to `some_value`.

Comment: I'm using this all the time to test for existence of params. Can you show more complete pipeline code? You are possibly trying to use `env` too early in the pipeline.

Comment: This is slightly confusing, because 1. the env keys are named differently between the two blocks of code 2. it is unclear whether the pipeline in the second block of code is the downstream of the first and, if so, what the `parameters` directive is for that pipeline.

Comment: My fault: the Jenkins job needs to be labeled as "parametrized" in the GUI and a string parameter needs to be added. Seems like you can't just invent a parameter, you need to define it in the job GUI first. See my answer below.

Comment: Btw, is there a way to avoid this parameter definition in the GUI?

Comment: Of course there is: `parameters { string(name: 'branch_my', defaultValue: 'master', description: '') }`

Comment: @Danijel I never really liked `parameters` because it only adds parameters to the GUI, it doesn't declare them as in a regular programming language. So you need a "dry run" before you can actually use the pipeline with parameters and again after every change to `parameters` declaration in script. Very counter-intuitive, especially for new developers coming from other programming languages.

Comment: @zett42 Thanks for the info - I didn't know `parameters` just adds the parameter to the GUI. I might as well just use the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Problem isn't the Jenkinsfile syntax, but the Jenkins job configuration: it must be labeled as "parametrized" in the GUI and a string parameter `branch_my` needs to be defined:

[image: Jenkins parametrized job]

Note, the parameters can be added [via the Jenkinsfile](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parameters) itself:

`parameters { string(name: 'branch_my', defaultValue: 'master', description: '') }`

However, this just adds the parameter to the GUI, so you end up with the same thing.